# Running async functions simultaneously not updating state variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, asynchronous

I'm using ReactJS and trying to store the polyline returned by the Google Maps directions API in a state variable to be rendered conditionally later. This is the state variable that stores the first and second polylines:

```js
const [routes, setRoutes] = useState({1: null, 2: null})
```

The problem is that when I update them through an asynchronous function, only the 2nd field updates for some reason

This is the function call

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        drawTaxiRoute(0, data.taxis, data.origin, data.map, setRoutes, routes)
        drawTaxiRoute(1, data.taxis, data.origin, data.map, setRoutes, routes)
    }, [])
```

And this is the async function (I removed the `async` keyword but it still behaves asynchronously due to the callback)

```js
function drawTaxiRoute(N = 0, taxis, destination, map, setRoutes, routes) {
    ...

    directionsService.route(
        {
            origin: taxis[N].getPosition(),
            destination: destination,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        },
        function (result, status) {
            if (status == 'OK') {
                taxiRouteDisplay.setMap(map)
                setRoutes({...routes, [N+1]: result})
                console.log(result, N+1)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

According to the inspect element console, results is correctly returning the polyline, but the `routes` state is being incorrectly updated such that one is null:

`{1: null, 2: {...}}`

I suspect the issue is that `routes` is not updated in time for first time since it's running in parallel so it's still `null` when the 2nd async invocation starts and gets overwritten. Can anyone suggest a way to populate both polylines in `route`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last call will overwrite the first, because when `setRoutes` is called, the value of `routes` is still the one passed on the parameter of `drawTaxiRoutes`

If you don't know, the setter method returned by `useState` can take two types of arguments: the type of the variable, and a callback returning the new value.
This callback takes one parameter, the current value of the variable.

So instead of passing `routes` as a parameter of your method, you can do something like this :

```
setRoutes((oldValue) => ({...oldValue, [N+1]: result}))
```

That way, the value of `oldValue` will always be the last updated value.

Hope it helps :)